# how to add Permissions in Django to Models and Test it using the shell

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I added the Meta class in my model and synchronized the DB then created an object in the shell
it returns false so i really cant understand where is the error or what is missing is there some sort of configuration maybe in some other files ..

```
class Employer(User): # Employer inherits from User
    employer_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("is_member", "Friendly permission description"),
        )

emp = Employer.objects.create(blablabla)
emp.save()
emp.has_perm('myappname.is_member')
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the example you gave, I would expect `emp.has_perm('myappname.is_member')` to indeed be `False`. Unless you explicitly give the new `Employer` object the `is_member` permission, it won't have it.

To programmatically give it the permission you need to get the actual permission object and add it to the `Employer`'s `user_permissions`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Employer)
permission = Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type, codename='is_member')

emp = Employer.objects.create(blablabla)
emp.save()
emp.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

To test it in the shell, you may need to delete the permission cache that is created for each user- otherwise `has_perm` may not reflect the actual permissions:

```
delattr(emp, '_perm_cache')
```

**Responding to your questions:**

If you want every single `Employer` to have the `is_member` permission there are a few options:

1. Override the `save` method of `Employer` to check if there is no `self.pk` (which means it is a new object, and create the permission as I showed above after saving.  Not very pretty, but it would work.
2. Write your own [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend). If the permission code is `'is_member'` and the `User` has an `Employer` instance, return `True`
3. Don't use permissions. The permission system is designed for you to be able to dynamically grant and revoke permissions. If you only care whether a `User` is an `Employer`- then test for that. Don't complicate it by using permissions.

Comment: ok if i want to add the permission just to the model meaning that every object created from that model have this permissions what should i do in the model??? excuse me .. but i am very confused

Comment: That's not how permissions work. Adding the `is_member` permission doesn't mean that every `Employee` will have that permission. It means that any `Employee` has the _option_ of having that permission.

Comment: Excellent answer. +1 for mentioning delattr(emp, '_perm_cache'), I was having troubles while playing with permissions in the shell.

Comment: One more, thing. There's also a _group_perm_cache attribute that you need to delete in case your user instance is inheriting permissions from groups. It may be easier to simply reload the user with something like u = User.objects.get(username='username'), that's what a test in django.contrib.auth does.