# Setting Django admin permissions programmatically

Tags: django, django-admin

The Django site I'm working on has the possibility for users to sign up for an account. To provide them with some editing functionality, I use the built-in Django admin. However, I'm having a problem: After a user has signed up, they don't have any permissions inside the Django admin, not even view permissions. Thus my question: How do I, in code, assign admin permissions to the user for the relevant models, in the same way I can assign them manually in the "User Permissions" section when editing the user in the admin? I've already tried with the [usual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission) `has_xxx_permissions()` using custom `ModelAdmin` classes, but that didn't work. So my guess is that I overlooked something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131271/invalid-literal-error-when-adding-a-user-permission-to-a-django-user-object/10131510#10131510) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252332/how-to-add-permissions-in-django-to-models-and-test-it-using-the-shell/10252613#10252613).

Answer (score 9):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

```
new_user.user_permissions.add(permission1, permission2, etc...)
```

Comment: Only `user.user_permissions.add()` worked for me. Django 1.4 raised `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'permissions'` if I tried just ``user.permissions.add()``.

Answer (score 6):

For your purposes, it would probably be much more easy and and efficient to assign all new users to a particular group, and then give that group all the permissions the user needs. Any member of the group will inherit those permissions as well.

You can create the group and assign the permissions to it in the admin. Then, you just need to add something like the following to your registration code.

```
try:
    group = Group.objects.get(name='The User Group')
except Group.DoesNotExist:
    # group should exist, but this is just for safety's sake, it case the improbable should happen
    pass
else:
    user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: I suppose it could be done this way, but applying the permissions directly to the users seems "nicer" to me (okay, probably just a matter of taste). But I'll keep this in mind for other use cases.

Comment: @Timo I'm exactly the same; even though in theory a group is more elegant, it's another thing to make sure is in place. I think when I need to do this sort of thing more I'll switch to groups, but for now I'm going to stick with direct perms.

Comment: Actually, dgel's code samples (linked to [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10863809/61938)) changed my mind. Groups it is!

Answer (score 3):

[dgel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473232/dgel)'s answer pointed me in the direction which lead to a working solution for me.  Essentially, what he seems to be suggesting is:

1. Retrieve a [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType) for the model you want to set permissions for. In this context, a content type is an object that holds [information about a Django model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).
2. Create a [Permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.models.Permission) object consisting of the content type and the action you want to allow inside the admin, using `Permission.objects.get()`. The only difficulty here is figuring out the `codename` parameter, which, for admin permissions, consists of an action ("add", "change" or "delete"), an underscore, and the model name. So if you have a model called `Foo` and you want to create all permissions for it, you'll need 3 permissions, each with the content type of your `Foo` model plus the code names `add_foo`, `change_foo`, and `delete_foo`.
3. Assign these permissions using `user.user_permissions.add(permission)`.

Head over to dgel's answers for [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131271/invalid-literal-error-when-adding-a-user-permission-to-a-django-user-object/10131510#10131510) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252332/how-to-add-permissions-in-django-to-models-and-test-it-using-the-shell/10252613#10252613). Looking at a data dump of the auth app (`manage.py dumpdata auth`) of an existing Django database provided me with insights into the inner workings of permissions, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer your question exactly since I found this question with Google. I'll show what I'm doing in Django 1.9 with groups, then show how to do it to a user.

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
    group, __ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='my_group')

```
permissions = Permission.objects.all()
for p in permissions:
    group.permissions.add(p)
group.save()
```

It's pretty easy to adapt to user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
permissions = Permission.objects.all()
for p in permissions:
    youruser.user_permissions.add(p)
youruser.save()
```

I prefer group because you may be adding permissions in the future and can just add to group instead of re-doing all users.

Comment: is `youruser.save()` or `group.save()` necessary? This is a m2m link - and group.permissions.add(p) should be everything you need. no `save()` necessary IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 1.6:

Every User has a many-to-many field `user_permissions` to Permission - you can add permissions to this:

```
your_user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

v1.6 Docs:

- [Django.contrib.auth API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.user_permissions) (shows User, Group and Permission objects)
- [Auth default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.user_permissions) (shows how to clear, add, remove)